# syntax error at or near "$1" when using npgsql

Tags: c#, npgsql, postgresql-9.4

I am currently trying to update npgsql.

I had a method that was working perfectly using the old npgsql version, but when I run it with the new npgsql 3.2.6 it fails with the exception:

> 42601: syntax error at or near "$1"

This is my code, passed to a console application, that reproduces this error:

```
Console.WriteLine("Start");

NpgsqlConnection con = null;
NpgsqlCommand cmd = null;

try
{
    con = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=...;Port=...;Username=...;Password=...;Database=...");
    con.Open();

    cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SET APPLICATION_NAME=@app_name;", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@app_name", "test");

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (cmd != null)
        cmd.Dispose();

    if (con != null)
        con.Dispose();
}

Console.WriteLine("End");
Console.ReadKey();
```

I also noticed that if I set the query to `SET APPLICATION_NAME='@app_name';` it works. But it should work without the '... I have also tried to specify the variable type with `NpgsqlDbType` but still no luck.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

The exception is thrown at the line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`.

Comment: Which line is it throwing on?

Comment: at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();